# ¿Cómo elimino las lineas en blanco al imprimir un archivo de modo de replicar el contenido?

Tags: python

```
f = open('Nombres.txt')
for line in f:   
  print(line)   

f.close()
```

Este código lo he copiado y pegado de aquí: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files

Me ha parecido la forma más simple de hacerlo, pero falla en que lo que devuelve son lineas de texto separadas por un espacio en blanco.

Comment: Creo que la solución más simple para ti es usar print(line, end=‘’). Con el parámetro end evitas que python inserte un salto de línea adicional al final de cada línea.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es simple: cuando Python lee una línea desde un archivo de texto, incluye en ella el `'\n'` al final de ella.

La función `print()` automáticamente agrega un `'\n'` al final de lo que imprime. Entonces tienes dos `'\n'` seguidos: uno que venía del archivo original y otro que agrega el `print()`.

**Solución**

Usa la función `rstrip()` para eliminar los espacios en blancos (`'\n'` incluido) al final de la línea.

```
f = open('nombres.txt')
for line in f:   
  print(line.rstrip())

f.close()
```

Existe la función `lstrip()`, que elimina espacios por la izquierda y también `strip()`, que elimina por ambos lados.